# InterpolatingFunction with growing Domain

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, interpolation

I want to find roots of a function that is very slow to calculate (the function itself involves a bunch of FindMaxima) so I interpolate the function in a region where I think it likely the the root is, since I have very little certainty where the root is I have to interpolate an absurdly large region.

Is there a way to have InterpolatingFunction remember the original function and expand its domain when evaluation is attempted outside it?

Comment: If you are willing to try different interpolation methods then there may be something [here](http://www.familydahl.se/mathematica/) of relevance.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That's some really neat ways to do interpolation, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that sadly it has a little bit of overhead making it slower to evaluate. When argument is outside domain it interpolates towards that direction and creates a new InterpolatingFunction by merging together with the old one.

```
(*   f: function to interpolate
    x0: Starting position
  size: minimum interval to interpolate each time
 order: InterpolatingOrder 
*)
AutoInterpolatingFunction[f_, x0_, size_, opts:OptionsPattern[FunctionInterpolation]] :=
 Module[{
   wrap,
   if},
  wrap["if"] = 
   FunctionInterpolation[
    f[\[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], x0 - size, x0 + size}, 
    opts];
  wrap["f"] = f;
  wrap["xmin"] = x0 - size;
  wrap["xmax"] = x0 + size;
  (* Argument in domain *)
  wrap[x_?NumericQ] := wrap["if"][x] /; wrap["xmin"] <= x <= wrap["xmax"];
  (* Interpolate a bit further *)
  wrap[x_?NumericQ] :=
   Module[{newf},
    If[x > wrap["xmax"],
     newf = FunctionInterpolation[
       wrap["f"][\[FormalX]],
       {\[FormalX], wrap["xmax"], Max[wrap["xmax"] + size, x]},
       opts];
     wrap["if"] = 
      Interpolation[{Join[wrap["if"]["Grid"], Rest@newf["Grid"]],
         Join[wrap["if"]["ValuesOnGrid"], 
          Rest@newf["ValuesOnGrid"]]}\[Transpose]];
     wrap["xmax"] = wrap["if"]["Domain"][[1, 2]]
     ,
     newf = 
      FunctionInterpolation[
       wrap["f"][\[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], 
        Min[x, wrap["xmin"] - size], wrap["xmin"]},
       opts];
     wrap["if"] = 
      Interpolation[{Join[newf["Grid"], Rest@wrap["if"]["Grid"]],
         Join[newf["ValuesOnGrid"], 
          Rest@wrap["if"]["ValuesOnGrid"]]}\[Transpose]];
     wrap["xmin"] = wrap["if"]["Domain"][[1, 1]]
     ];
    wrap["if"][x]];
  wrap
  ]
```

A simple speed test:

```
aip = AutoInterpolatingFunction[Sin[#] Cos[#] &, 0, 1];
ip = FunctionInterpolation[Sin[x] Cos[x], {x, 0, 1}];
AbsoluteTiming[Do[ip[0.5], {100000}]]
AbsoluteTiming[Do[aip[0.5], {100000}]]
(* 1.7s vs 0.7s *)
```